# EclipseLink batch writing not working in a JPA/JTA application

Tags: spring, jpa, eclipselink

I am writing a JPA application on Glassfish 3.1.2.2, EclipseLink 2.3.2.  I am using Spring MVC as well, with the container-managed EntityManager (`@PersistenceContext` injected by Spring, but created by container via `jee:jndi-lookup`)

I set `eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing` to `JDBC` in persistence.xml and it's not working as expected.

My code has a fairly simple loop to write a bunch of objects

```
 UserTransaction tx = ...;
 tx.begin();
 for (MyObject obj : list) { 
   entityManager.persist(obj);
 }
 tx.commit();
```

Batch writing *does* work if I replace UserTransaction with a `@Transactional` annotation around the method though!

I see a separate unit of work created for **each** persist call:

```
FINER: client acquired: 3418589
FINER: TX binding to tx mgr, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
FINER: acquire unit of work: 11053522
FINEST: persist() operation called on: mypkg.MyClass@1252ed8
....
FINER: client acquired: 23361578
FINER: TX binding to tx mgr, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
FINER: acquire unit of work: 17636998
FINEST: persist() operation called on: mypkg.MyClass@1252ed8
```

The DB operations don't actually execute until the commit, as expected - but each unit of work has its own batch:

```
FINER: TX beforeCompletion callback, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
FINER: begin unit of work commit
FINER: TX beginTransaction, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
FINEST: Execute query InsertObjectQuery(mypkg.MyClass@12a46ef)
FINEST: Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
FINEST: Execute query  
FINER: Begin batch statements
FINE: INSERT INTO ....
FINE:   bind => [24 parameters bound]
FINER: End Batch Statements
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?  I think the root of the problem is the separate unit of work per persist.

**NOTE** I *do* see batching work for child entities that are cascaded through a single persist, within a single unit of work.  But each set of parent/children is a resulting in a separate batch.

Comment: Which JDBC driver you were using & does it support batch writing.

Comment: Oracle.  The JDBC driver support batching when I use JDBC directly (not through JPA)

Comment: Also see comment in edit

Comment: This is a spring config issue, as it seems each persist is occurring on a different EntityManager context underneath the spring EM wrapper.  Spring is starting a new EM for each persist call, forcing each insert to be in a separate statement, while batching requires they all be in a single EM context.  Please show the spring settings for how the EM is obtained.  You can also try getting the delegate EclipseLink EM from the wrapper and reusing it as a workaround.

Comment: @Chris - you're right, although I noticed the same behavior in a Java EE/JSF application when using UserTransaction.  Is that a Spring bug? Or a Java EE bug?  (@Transactional annotation doesn't have this problem.)  Thanks for the tip on  unwrapping.  Make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

- For Oracle, you can try configuring it in persistence.xml.

  `<property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="Oracle-JDBC"/>`

  From Documentation :

  > **oracle-jdbc** : Use the Oracle platform's native batch writing. In a property map, use OracleJDBC.
  >
  > Note: This requires an Oracle JDBC driver.
- Else, it can also be configured through property.

  `propertyMap.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.BATCH_WRITING, BatchWriting.OracleJDBC);`

In conjunction with batch writing, can have `eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size` to specify the batch size.

*[The post is EclipseLink specific, I am not much familiar with Spring]*

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing Java EE transactions and Spring transactions.  You need to use one or the other.

If you want to use JTA, you need to configure your persistence.xml to use JTA, and ensure that you are setting the "eclipselink.target-server" correctly (it will be set by default if you access it from Glassfish, but if you access it from Spring it will not).

Comment: persistence.xml was already set up to use JTA.  eclipselink.target-server was already set.  And Spring was configured to use `<tx:jta-transaction-manager>` so the Spring `@Transactional` annotation was still using underlying JTA transactions.